# overload standard erc-20 methods in solidity

Tags: solidity, erc-20

Can I overload and use standard ERC-2O methods?

For example:

- Standard function : transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns
  (bool success)
- Overload function : transfer(address to, uint tokens,    uint param1,
  uint256 param2)
- standard function: transferFrom(address from, address to, uint
  tokens) public returns (bool success)
- Overload function:
  transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens, uint param1,
  uint256 param2) public returns (bool success)

Comment: Yes, you can...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. You can add any extra functionality you want, as long as the required functions with the correct signature are present.